# What's the TV episode from the 1950s or 60s about a wife whose husband is a doppelganger?

Tags: story-identification, horror

This is probably an episode from an American anthology show but I can't track it down. The wife's husband is killed (I think it's in a car crash) but is replaced by a doppelganger in the hospital. She knows it's not really him but nobody believes her. She has a young son. That's all I can remember.

Comment: Is the doppelganger a clone? Robot? Something else? This isn't immediately on topic, could you [edit] to clarify? Was he killed on purpose? Why was he replaced?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: in a similar vein: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Parallel (Twilight Zone - Season 4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the *Hammer House of Horror* episode, [*The Two Faces of Evil*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0274175/?ref_=tt_urv).

> A hitch-hiker dressed in yellow oil skins attacks the driver of a car who has stopped to give him a lift. The car crashes and the driver fights with the insane hitch-hiker. It appears like the driver, though badly injured, has prevailed and is taken to hospital. The drivers wife subsequently learns that her husband has damaged his throat in the struggle and is unable to talk, she is also asked to identify the body of the madman. The body looks exactly like her husband and doubts begin to enter her mind as to which of the two is the killer.

Comment: Warning. The end of this episode is freaky-deaky

Comment: The grammar in your quoted paragraph is awful. Who writes this stuff?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's a review by an IMDB user. I've swapped it out for a more fulsome one

Comment: Thanks so much! It is the Hammer episode, Two faces of Evil! That is great. Was this the right forum? The answers below seem a bit unhappy with my question. I am sorry. I am new to this and do have other questions, but don't want to be asking the questions in the wrong forum. Once again, thanks so much.

Comment: Someone might remember a story, movie, whatever and sincerely believe it to be SF.  In this case that seems even likelier than normal given the replacement of a character, a plot device with heavy SF vibes to it.

Comment: @avasey - This was indeed the right forum. [Horror fantasy falls into the category of fantasy.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9671/20774)

Comment: Thanks all. And I am eternally grateful Valorum!

Comment: @valorum - I have never heard of this series before, and it appears to filmed in England.  I enjoyed it greatly, and will watch other episodes in the future!  What confuses me(being from the US but having watched a great deal of British TV, mostly comedy), however, is the fact that, while they referred to the "windshield" of the auto as a "windscreen", which I would expect, they also said "Going on vacation"(should be "holiday"), "A few hundred Yards"(instead of meters), and "A quarter of a mile"(instead of "kilometers".  Why the inconsistencies????

Comment: @Hitek - All of those are perfectly acceptable in British English. It's incredibly rare to use kilometres, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a straight thriller, and not horror/sci-fi, then  a) this is the wrong forum, and b) it's been done several times.  It might be :

1. [Chase a Crooked Shadow.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chase_a_Crooked_Shadow)
   A woman's brother, not husband, is supposedly dead, but a man claims to be him.  Movie, British, 1958
2. [Honeymoon With a Stranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeymoon_with_a_Stranger)
   A loose remake of the above, this time it's the woman's husband that's replaced. TV Movie USA, 1969

Comment: Thanks Pete, I consider it a horror/sci-fi, but not sure of the criteria because only just discovered this site. I will try to improve the wording on future questions, but honestly, the body of my question included all the details I could remember. Kind regards.